# Raspberry PI, USB device location

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am fairly new with Raspberry Pi, and I have a rather silly question that seems to trouble me for an hour or so.

I have an usb device connected to my raspberry pi and I need to send some files there however I can't seem to find the location of the device in my file explorer anywhere. Any suggestions?

I am using raspbian stretch, and I have a raspberry B+ model.

Cheers,
Marcel

Comment: What usb device? A USB powered fan?

Comment: [Did you try to find it on raspberrypi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=usb+device)

Comment: Sorry, a flash drive, but it doesn't matter turns out it was just not correctly formatted and I didn't think of that. My bad!